# How to use Boost.Signals2 connect_extended?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

I have a working Boost.Signals2 `signal` & `slot` combination in my C++ project & set up like so;

```
//DECLARE SIGNAL
signals2::signal<void (const EN_DATA_STREAM, long, double, double, double, double,     double)> signal;

//CONNECT DATAUPDATE() OF CANDIDATE INSTANCE
signal.connect(bind(&Candidate::DataUpdate, candidateInstance, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7));
    
//FIRE SIGNAL
signal(iDataNumber, BarNumber(), DateTime(), Open(), High(), Low(), Close());
```

I've been trying to take this further and use the `boost.signals2` `connect_extended` functionality as I'd like to pass details of the invoking `signal` to the `slot` so that the `slot` may disconnect itself from the `signal` at some later time.  The syntax for this is escaping me.  Please could someone demonstrate how to convert the above code so that it uses `connect_extended` to pass connection information to the `slot`.

P.S.  I've been looking at this example provided at the boost website but am still none the wiser as to how to tailor it to my requirements where the parameters use `bind`.

[Boost.Signals2 connect_extended example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/signals2/example/extended_slot.cpp)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantage of `connect_extended` is that it allows the slot to receive `connection` object, which may be crucial in a multi-threaded program, where slot invocation might occur in another thread before `connect_extended` returns. You do not need `connect_extended` to pass any other information, as you can bind it directly. Anyway, here is how you can do this with `connect_extended`:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

using namespace boost::signals2;

void your_slot(connection conn, int, double, int, char)
{
}

int main()
{
  signal<void(int, double, int)> your_signal;
  your_signal.connect_extended(boost::bind(&your_slot, _1, _2, _3, _4, 'a'));
  your_signal(1, 2.0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Igor R.  Your example was really helpful. Once I realised to add an extra placeholder for the connection object my code compiled and ran.